# Windows 10 Task Scheduler run PowerShell with no pop-up window

Tags: windows, powershell, task-scheduler

I want to set up a task scheduler to run a PowerShell script every 1 hour with no prompt windows pop-up.

Here is the command I tried:

```
schtasks /create /sc hourly /tn $Task-Name /st $ScheduleTime `
/tr "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command C:\MyScript.ps1" `
```

I added all parameters I found.

```
-windowstyle hidden -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile
```

The script runs in the background with no problem but it still at the beginning pops up for a second before hides itself.

Does anyone know how to make a task scheduler to run the ps1 script fully hide with no pop-up windows?

Comment: To run a command script and hide the window from appearing, call the task using [VBScript.Run](https://ss64.com/vb/run.html).

Comment: @JosefZ I refer to your link and solve the issue by the VBS. Thank you so much! Could you please post the answer below? Then I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am achieving this via the task scheduler, i have set the action value to start a powershell program with the following arguments:

```
-executionpolicy bypass -noninteractive -file "C:\PathToYourScript"
```

[image]

the key argument here is -noninteractive, it does not present an interactive prompt to the user.

Comment: OP literally says he started with the "noninteractive" flag.